# I don't understand how define Types in Julia

Tags: types, julia

I'm learning Julia, and I'm just a little bit confused about Types.
Mine is a very basic question. I understand that if I write

```
x = 64.0::MyType
```

x should be contain the value 64, with Type equal to MyType. But if I write

```
x = 64.0::Float32
```

I get the error

```
ERROR: TypeError: in typeassert, expected Float32, got Float64
```

I found that the following does not give me an error

```
x = convert(Float32,64.0)
```

Is this the right approach? It seems too convoluted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answers from @NilsGudat and @DaveNewton are both correct but incomplete, so let me provide some elaboration.

It's important to note that your first example, `x = 64.0::MyType`, is *not* how you create a number of type `MyType`. The notation `a::MyType`, when it occurs on the right-hand side of an expression, is a type assertion. It will return the value of `a` if `a` is a subtype of `MyType` (`a isa MyType`), but if `a` is not a subtype of `MyType` it throws an exception. In your everyday Julia code, you are not likely to need this very often. For more information on type declarations and assertions, see the manual section on [type declarations](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#Type-Declarations-1) and [this section](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#Annotate-values-taken-from-untyped-locations-1) from the performance tips.

As @DaveNewton points out, Julia provides a [literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(computer_programming)) syntax for creating `Float32` numbers. The syntax is analogous to the scientific notation for `Float64`, e.g. `4.5e2`, except the `e` is replaced with an `f`:

```
julia> 4.5f2
450.0f0

julia> 450f0
450.0f0

julia> typeof(4.5f2)
Float32
```

Note that attaching `::Float32` to a `Float32` literal value is not necessary and is in fact redundant. So instead of writing `x = 64.0f0::Float32` as suggested by @DaveNewton, you can just write `x = 64.0f0`.

Comment: I agree with you

Answer (score 8):

Julia defaults to `Float64`. `Float32` literals need an `f` (as opposed to an `e`):

```
x = 64.0f0::Float32
```

As Renat adds:

https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/integers-and-floating-point-numbers/

(Which is what I used to answer this question since I don't know Julia. But I know how to search :)

Comment: Reference: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/integers-and-floating-point-numbers/

Comment: Thank you. It still seems too convolute to me

Comment: @niandra82 What's convoluted about it? Julia has default literals, if you don't want the default, you need to explicitly specify the conversion.

Comment: I found it not intuitive. But probably I have just to lean better julia philosophy

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the input `64.0` is automatically a `Float64`:

```
julia> typeof(64.0)
Float64
```

Therefore you want to directly construct a `Float32` like so:

```
julia> Float32(64.0)
64.0f0

julia> typeof(ans)
Float32
```

Comment: This is not "directly constructing a `Float32`" but converting a `Float64` to `Float32`. Constructing a `Float32` directly would be `64.0f0`.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax you wrote down is, you defined a Float64 and then declared that it should be a Float32, and so it rightly throws an error saying that's not compatible. `64.0` or `64e0` is a Float64, while `64f0` is a Float32. So `x = 64f0` is all you need. Such type assertions are generally not needed except for controlling dispatch or defining the fields of a struct.

Comment: dispatch and struct is exactly why I need it

Comment: You are not defining a dispatch or a struct so no, you don't need it here. In fact, all it does is check the type and error in your case.

Comment: This was just a simple example to show what I didn't understand.  But in my code, i want to use it for dispatch and struct ;-)